# headers sent in php after output STILL working

Tags: php, http-headers

I have this simple script:

```
this is output!

<?php

header("Location: http://www.google.com");

?>
```

You believe it or not it works and I get no warnings either!

The manual says no output should be done before sending headers or no headers will be actually sent. But it does work anyway and it is annoying me.

Comment: You've got output buffering turned on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is possible because of [output buffers](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.outcontrol.php).

Comment: the one that you see up there is the only code being executed. I'm not buffering anything. I might have forgotten to mention that the redirect is actually executed! Crazy.

Comment: Output buffering is a built-in mechanism of PHP. It may be enabled in your [php.ini](http://www.php.net/manual/en/outcontrol.configuration.php).

Comment: great! you won mate! It was the .ini