# Why is this else if not getting executed?

Tags: php

I have the following code

```
<?php

ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('log_errors', TRUE);
ini_set('html_errors', FALSE);
ini_set('error_log', '/var/www/vhosts/*******/test/random/error.log');
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);


require "./func/dbc.php";

define("IN_MYBB", 1);
require "../global.php";

if (!$mybb->user['uid']) {
    die();
}

if (!empty($_GET['val'])) {
    if (is_numeric($_GET['val'])) {
        if (intval($_GET['val']) >= 10) {
            $rating = 10;
        } else if (intval($_GET['val']) <= 1) {
            $rating = 1;
        } else {
            $rating = intval($_GET['val']);
        }

    }
}

if ($_GET['type'] == "rating") {
    //Some Database Querys that don't cause any errors. :)
} else if ($_GET['type'] == "rating2") {
    echo "entering if";
//other sql querys. :)
}
header("Location: view.php");

?>
```

The file is called **rate.php**, when I open it like this

```
rate.php?type=rating&val=10
```

It runs perfectly fine, but when I open it like this

```
rate.php?type=rating2&val=10
```

Nothing happens, I added the echo to check if it'll enter the else if - It won't, I'll just get redirected to **view.php** again.

Comment: You may have output buffering on, as is your script looks correct: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13180649/headers-sent-in-php-after-output-still-working

Comment: Oh... that's why I didn't see my echo. I didn't know I enabled output buffering, but I managed to resolve the issue with some "debug echos" :D Thanks.